# How to install Python 3.9.14 on Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-3.9

Python 3.9.14 has been released on Sept. 6, 2022. As I can see written on https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3914/:

> According to the release calendar specified in PEP 596, Python 3.9 is
> now in the "security fixes only" stage of its life cycle: the 3.9
> branch only accepts security fixes and releases of those are made
> irregularly in source-only form until October 2025. Python 3.9 isn't
> receiving regular bug fixes anymore, and binary installers are no
> longer provided for it. Python 3.9.13 was the last full bugfix release
> of Python 3.9 with binary installers.

Is there a safe way to install a 64-bit version of Python 3.9.14 on Windows?

Comment: Seems there are no binaries even on their FTP server [Py3.9 FTP](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.14/)! But, since Py3.9 is no longer provided a binary installer as stated in your quoted disclaimer, you will have to build it yourself.

Answer (score 7):

"Note: The release you're looking at is Python 3.9.14, a security bugfix release for the legacy 3.9 series. Python 3.10 is now the latest feature release series of Python 3. Get the latest release of 3.10.x"

Do try unofficial version here: https://github.com/adang1345/PythonWindows/tree/master/3.9.14

Comment: Nice, I tried to compile the 3.7.16 version, stuck with a stupid git problem, but this is awesome, I didn't know, there are unofficial versions around! Big THX